# Voltage shifter distorts signal

Tags: level-shifting, level-translation

I am trying to downshift a 5V TTL signal to 3V logic signal using [NTB0102](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTB0102_Q100.pdf) level shifter. The connection is described below:

[image]

However, my oscilloscope measurements are distorted. Even the input signal (out of the microcontroller pin-pin connected) does not look like a true TTL 0-5V signal:

[image]

Placing caps on VCC does not help. Reversing the propagation way (0-3V input to 0-5V output) also produces ugly picture. Pulling UP/DOWN microcontrollre's output pin does not make a difference. Any ideas about what's going on?

The layout:

[image]

After someone suggested using 10x probes, I have an improvement in the output signal, but it still does not like a square wave:

[image]

Comment: Did you connect the probe grounds properly?

Comment: Is the uC connected to the same ground as the translator?

Comment: @ErikFriesen I hope I did. They are connected at the place all grounds.

Comment: @ThePhoton All grounds are connected in one place.

Comment: Is this built on a pcb or breadboard? If it's a breadboard can you give us a photo of the construction? If it's a pcb can you show us the layout?

Comment: @ThePhoton I added the picture to the question body. Could the grounding cause such distortions?

Comment: I don't really like the big loop from NTB0102 to the main ground bus. Or the really really long loop for the bypassing capacitor on the uC. Does the circuit work if you reduce the signal rate to 2 kHz (for example)? But really, I don't think those are the problem. (See next comment)

Comment: There's somethign fishy about the way the uC isn't pulling it's output down for the low levels. Which pins on the uC are ground?

Comment: I see a blue and a red wire at lower right, which appear to be 5V and "ground". At top I see a cliplead labeled 3V. At bottom I see two clips which appear to be the scope ground connections. Where is the other power supply ground attached? Since the 2313 seems to be giving the proper waveform, presumably your power supply ground provides a return for 3 volts. If there is no similar connection to the 5V power supply ground, that would explain things.

Comment: @ThePhoton I made the long loop shorter, reduced the rate to 5Khz, exchanged the NTB0102 and microcontroller - no significant changes. Pin 20 = GND (yellow connected with shifter ground). The [ATTiny2313](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2543.pdf) should be able to pull up to 20mA (see page 199, note 3). Also, see page 17 of the NTB spec sheet section 13.6 - what means "For this reason the NTB0102 is not recommended for use in open drain driver applications such as 1-Wire or I2C-bus"?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The ground for 3V line is connected to the ground for 5V line at the power supply - so, three wires out of power supply: 3V, 5V, and GND.

Comment: @Naz . It looks like your green wire (ground for NTB) is on bottom side of your setup, and the ground for the TINY (blue wire) is on the top of board.  The ground current seems to have to run all way around the board. Perhaps try moving green Ground wire to top of board.

Comment: @Marla The vertical blue ground from the right is only used when programming the uC. The uC yellow ground goes to NTB ground, and then green to the bottom rail.

Comment: @Naz . Got it.  Try moving your bypass capacitor ground connection. (NTB) from ground rail, directly to pin 2 (NTB) which is ground. Also doing same for bypass capacitor on NTB pin 7.

Comment: @Naz, if the uC pin 20 is ground, then I think the cap at its lower right has both pins grounded. Did you maybe mean pin 10 is ground?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry, I meant pin 10 is the ground. Also, I removed the caps. How do you understand the statement  from the NTB's data sheet "To avoid output contention issues, any pull-up or pull-down resistors used must be above 50 k. For this reason the NTB0102 is not recommended for use in open drain driver applications such as 1-Wire or I2C-bus. For these applications, the NTS0102 level translator is recommended". Could this anything to do with my uC? I tried to use 100k pulldown on uC pin - did not help.

Comment: @Marla I tried. And now, I removed them off the board.

Comment: @Naz . you do need both capacitors. My point was to bring the capacitors ground legs all together on NTB pin 2. Your capacitor ground lead for pin7 capacitor was going to bottom rail, and capacitor ground lead for pin3 capacitor was going to top rail.

Comment: @Naz, the pull-up/pull-down issue should not be affecting you if you have the uC output set to be driving both high and low (rather than open-drain or psuedo-open-drain), and if you are using megohm-range scope probes.

Comment: @ThePhoton This is insane, but I think I found the problem. The NTB's Io is +/-50mA. Having my probe of 50 Ohm gives 3/50=60mA. After I buffered the NTB's output with opAmp, everything plays good. I hope it will do well in uC->NTB->ADC chain. Thank you.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well, although it seems to work now, my explanation does not hold. Since uC pin can drive 20mA (even less than NTB), I was supposed to have distorted reading directly from the uC as well. But it was fine. What do you think?

Comment: Naz - Not to be critical, but why in the name of all that's holy are you looking at 5 kHz logic signals with 50 ohms? Doesn't your scope have a high impedance input option (like 1MegOhm)? For looking at logic signals, high impedance is a must.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast you are right. I measured the impedance - it is 1M. But what's going on then? When I measure the output signal with oscilloscope directly from the NTB (pin 5), I get that ugly picture. However, when I use G=1 buffer, I get a reasonable output.

Comment: Ah. My guess is that you are driving your scope with a 1x probe. At these frequencies this does not work well. Get a pair of 10x probes, and perform a compensation cycle before you use them. The capacitance of the scope input is giving you problems. Only use 1x probes when looking at very low level, low frequency signals.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Well, switching to 10x helped a little. But the signal is still not as I wish it to be. Now, why don't I see the same problem in the uC's output? It seems to be ok with 1x or 10x probes? Also, post your explanation as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: This is turning into 20 questions.  Stack Exchange isn't really well suited to troubleshooting like this.  My advice, however, would be to take everything out of the breadboard, move up ten or fifteen rows, and build it again.  Also, at 2 MHz, is the reactance of the breadboard significant enough to cause problems?  I'm imagining capacitors between all the lines, and a little bit of mutual inductance to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more guesses:

The scope probe compensation is set badly.  The blue trace in your bottom scope plot looks like the poster case for this.

You have the "coupling" for that traces set to AC instead of DC.

Comment: Yes. The probe was at 1x. However, changing to 10x did not completely fix the problem. But the problem was indeed in the measurement technique. The signal was clean after **buffering** the NTB shifter.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation, and I know nothing about this chip, but perhaps the NTB0102 output pin-5 needs to have some kind of load on it to produce a clean signal.  After looking at the spec sheet for this device, the "test circuit" designates a load resistance to ground of 1 Meg ohms for measuring wave forms, and 50K ohms for some other types of measurements.  Maybe the load will dissipate some of that "noise".